# Principled BSDF don't appear

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, interface, edit-mode

[image]

Well, you can see, in Shader, P BSDF don't appear, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are editing a world shader, not a material.

World shaders don't really have a surface per-se so you obviously can't add surface based shaders like principled.

Change the shader context you are editing on the top left of the *Shader Editor* header from *World* to *Object*.

[image]